# In p4v, how to list "checked out" "out of sync" files for a certain folder?

Tags: perforce

https://www.perforce.com/video-tutorials/vcs/touring-p4v-interface
This has the p4v screenshot, in the left side is the Workspace window.

For any folder, if i right click it, the menu shows up.
But how to list "checked out" or "out of sync" files for this folder ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the command line, these are the commands `p4 opened` and `p4 sync -n`:

```
C:\Perforce\workshop\guest\sam_stafford\scripts>p4 opened ...
//guest/sam_stafford/scripts/itest.txt#1 - edit default change (text)

C:\Perforce\workshop\guest\sam_stafford\scripts>p4 sync -n ...
//guest/sam_stafford/scripts/p4rollback.pl#12 - updating c:\Perforce\workshop\guest\sam_stafford\scripts\p4rollback.pl
```

In P4V, all your open files (`p4 opened`) are in the "Pending Changelist" pane, and you can filter it to a path by dragging that folder to the filter part of the pane.

[image: pending changelist view]

The equivalent of `p4 sync` is "Get Revision...", which has a "Preview" option to let you do the `-n`:

[image: sync preview]